# How socket file is created in Gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am deploying a Django project using Gunicorn as application server and Nginx as a web server. This is the tutorial http://tutos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/ndg.html which I am following. Code for the gunicorn_start.sh (kept in the folder where the project resides).

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME="visualization"                                   
DJANGODIR=/var/www/dist/adc # Django project directory*
SOCKFILE=/var/www/dist/run/gunicorn.sock
USER=barun                                  
GROUP=barun                                    
NUM_WORKERS=1 
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=adc.settings  
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=adc.wsgi              
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment

cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/barun/anaconda3/envs/adcenv/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH
# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec /home/barun/anaconda3/envs/adcenv/bin/gunicorn 
${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \    #we should put the address 
gunicorn address
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user $USER \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

Code for gunicorn.service (/lib/systemd/system/gunicorn.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=visualization gunicorn daemon

[Service]
Type=simple
User=barun
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/dist
ExecStart=/home/barun/anaconda3/envs/adcenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --
bind unix:/var/www/dist/run/gunicorn.sock adc.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Everything is working fine. The location is given in gunicorn_start.sh file for creating a socket file, the run folder is created but gunicorn.sock file is not creating. There is not permission related problem

Apart from this, The error I am getting in Nginx error.log file is:

```
4783#4783: *1 connect() to unix:/var/www/dist/run/gunicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.1.213, server: 192.16.1.213, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/dist/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "172.16.1.213:8080"
```

When I am executing the ./gunicorn_start.sh the socket file should be created but it is not happening.

Comment: are there any gunicorn logs? Note that your `gunicorn.service` isn't using the `gunicorn_start.sh` script at all, so your environment variables aren't set. It's not clear from your question which of the two isn't working. What does `systemctl status gunicorn` tell you?

Comment: In your ExecStart you are using the gunicorn command directly instead of using the bash script you create why?

Comment: @dirkgroten it showing that Gunicorn is active. should I post the full-screen shot?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Initially I was using the location of the gunicorn_start.sh file in front of ExecStart. So, that was not working too, then I use above script.

Comment: And what is the logs from  of `systemctl status -l gunicorn`?

Comment: Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-10-05 10:26:14 IST; 2min 52s ago
 Main PID: 26925 (gunicorn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I have done everything from fresh. Uninstall and again install the Gunicorn and Nginx. delete all configuration file and write it again.
Now it's working well.